# Can any "relevant" topological spaces be decomposed into an uncountable product?

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples

Can any "relevant", as meaning generally useful topological spaces be decomposed into an uncountable product of other topological spaces with the product topology?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: $X = X \times \prod_\mathbb{R} *$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the case for some compactness arguments.

For example, have a look at the proof of the Banach-Alaoglou theorem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Alaoglu_theorem#Proof).

Here, one considers the unit ball in $X'$ as a subset of

$$
\prod_{x \in X} \overline{B}_{\Vert x \Vert}(0),
$$

where the ball is formed in $\Bbb{K}$ (i.e. $\Bbb{R}$ or $\Bbb{C}$).

One then uses Tychonoff's Theorem to conclude the compactness.